# How can I add text to a work item

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

We have a few bugs and change requests which have a complicated iteration path. This results in people coming over the team to ask 'Where do we raise items' a lot.

As you can't set a default value for the iteration path in TFS 2010 we think the best solution would be to add a string of text under the field which we can manually update every 7 weeks with the correct area to raise items in.

However TFS doesn't seem to allow just a line of text on its work items as a control. Is there a way to add a line of display text i.e. Not a field you edit, but just to inform those writing the items?

Please note that it needs to be visible at all times, using the tooltip 'help text' field on a control is not enough in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [LabelControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337625.aspx) for this purpose.

You can not have a default in the work item for the iteration path, but what you can do is making use or the [template url in web access](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/05/06/Initial-values-in-a-work-item.aspx) or the [work item templates in the power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) to create a work item that is prepopulated with values.

Answer (score 0):

What about a custom field with a display control in read-only? You can give a default value to the field and the "read-only" control prevent other to change it.